# How to retrieve the sender id of Kendo MultiSelectFor on change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo MultiSelectFor in a partial view. This partial view render these multi selects dynamically so their names are also dynamic. I am interested in getting the id when change event fires but seems like quite a difficult task

My multi select list is as follow

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(x => x.Widget.lstParameters[j].SelectedItems)
                                            .Name("widget-multiselectvalue-" + j)
                                            .BindTo(new MultiSelectList(Model.Widget.lstParameters[j].MSLDropDownList, "Value", "Text"))
                                            .Placeholder("--Please Select--")
                                            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "check-if-change" })
                                            .Events(e => e.Change("widget.msl_change"))
            )
```

following is my msl_change event

```
msl_change: function (e) {
    //var mslid = $(this)[0].id;
}
```

while looking at e.sender, it has _tagID which is quite close to the id of the multi select list. I can manipulate this tag id to get the required part but I really want to avoid this hack. The screen shot of e.sender is as follow

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close - the sender property on the event is an instance of the Kendo MultiSelect. Kendo instances have a property called "element" that holds a reference to its DOM element. Knowing that, you can access the ID in the change handler by using the following code:

```
var id = $(e.sender.element).prop("id");
```

Or, using the syntax from your commented out code:

```
var id = $(e.sender.element)[0].id
```

Or, just for good measure...:

```
$(e.sender.element).get(0).id
```

Comment: just wanted to thank you.  I wasn't passing the e into the function when i was trying to get the info.